iOS 16.2 SDK. Starting April 29, 2024, all iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later, included in Xcode 15
To fix the SDK version issue, found some suggestion to use macos-13 instead of macos-latest in azure devops pipeline (use azure repo)
But after changing to macos-13, i'm getting this error. please help me to fix it.
error MSB4226: The imported project "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" was not found.
i tried to use mac0s13 in azure devops hosted agent to fix SDK xcode version issue. but unfortunately getting runner issue
Expectation: need to fix runner issue
